# Launch independent process within rest API

Tags: c#, rest, createprocess

I am having a problem. We have a long running process, it takes about 13 minutes to process providers with large number of members. This is running up against the 100 second timeout for cloud rest services. We are looking into changing the process into a polling service. See our current Rest API method.

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult<PostResults>> PostPreLogic(PostRequest request)
{
    PreClient apiClient = ApiClientFactory.Instance;
    var (success, failure) = await _postBll.ProcessPostProvidersMembers(request, apiClient); //*** this is the long running process.

    var response = new PostResults()
    {
        RESP_CODE = "SUCCESS",
        RESP_MSG = "Complete",
        Success = success,
        Failure = failure,
        Request = request
    }

    return Ok(response);
}
```

I can't use a threading model because our code is anything but thread safe.

My problem is that I need to exit the method without waiting, but if I use a run or parallel task, it gets killed as soon as the method exits. Does anyone know how to create a separate process that will not be killed when the method returns.

Additionally once I get the process launched, is there a way to check on it's status directly without using a database.

Comment: How do you host your code? Also what do you mean by "a run or parallel task" and why do you think it could be a possible solution if "threading model" is not one due to "thread unsafety" of your code?

Comment: Our rest service is on an Azure Stack Cloud server, We determine recommendations, each recommendation takes about 7 seconds. Our new process can process 4,000 to 5,000 which takes a cumulative time of about 13 minutes.

Comment: Sorry, wrong button. We are running into timeouts Apparently Cloud places a ~100 seconds timeout when calling the rest service. When I try to change the processing into a polling service, so we can check the status using another method.  But when I attempt to launch the  long process, as soon as I exit the rest service. it kills the process, I need to start the process so it won't be killed when the methods exist

Comment: Another way I considered but ending up rejected it. Threading can help improve performance, but the way the algorithm was written using global variables, and resources. So we couldn't use threading unless we completely re-write everything

Comment: Thanks for any help you can provide